# zend framework login form without using zend_form

Tags: zend-framework

I need to create login form but with out using zend_form,
So where to create and how to post and fetch form fields.?

Comment: You can try the tutorial from the official site. A simple tutorial with an album application. Also, you can try zfcuser. Good luck, been there. D

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow is not made to get your code made by others. You are expected to try yourself and if you are stuck with a particular part you can come here and ask for help. I will start you off for now

#### HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/account/login">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This points to the controller `account` and the action `login`

#### Controller

```
<?php
    class AccountController {

          public function loginAction() {
              // Get the request
              $request = $this->getRequest();

              // If the request was a post we process the login request
              if ( $request->isPost() ) {
                        $email      = $request->getParam('email');
                        $password   = $request->getParam('password');
                   // Login procedure       
              }
          }
    }
```